# is delayed job will work rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

Will delayed job work with Rails 4?

Currently, I am upgrading my application to Rails 4 and using

```
gem "delayed_job", :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git'
```

in gemfile.

when i run `rake jobs:work` i got error like this

> Error while reserving job: undefined method reserve for
>   Delayed::Job:Class

any help on this?

Comment: Have you read the `README.md` [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` line below `gem "delayed_job"` to your gem file like this,

```
gem "delayed_job", :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git' 
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

and do

```
bundle install
```

then try

> bundle exec rake jobs:work

hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed job will work on rails 4. But the delayed_job folder inside the bin folder.
So, You can run delayed job by following command

```
bin/delayed_job start`
```